# Manual generating OAuth Access tokens

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I am looking to using OAuth to secure some web services. OAuth 2 fits nicely for the use cases I have where the user might access his/her own data using API's or grant access to someone to call API's on his behalf.

However, the initial set of API users are not very technical and they would not want to go through the effort of making API calls just to generate tokens. I am thinking of implementing the following solution but am not sure if this is the right way.

If the user is a developer, then

1. Have a screen where he/she can register an application. This will generate an API key/secret pair.
2. To access his/her own data (For 2 legged Auth) have a UI screen where the user can generate a access token for one his registered applications. He can specify the scopes and duration in the form.
3. If he is a 3rd party developer, then he needs to pass his applications API key to the person on whose behalf he needs to access the API and get an access token in exchange.

If the user wants a another application/developer to access API's on his behalf then

1. Have a screen where he can enter the third party's API key, scopes and the duration of the authorization. He can pass the generated access token to the developer who'll access the API's

I am going to use same OAuth libraries to generate the token that I would have used if I had gone the web service route. Further, I can also develop services whenever the current situation doesn't scale or the need arises and the existing tokens would still work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly one of security. By design, duration of access token should not be set by a client. If someone else gets to know the access token and client id during this duration, this user's account will be compromised. Normally this duration is set to be not very long and a second secret value refresh token is used to refresh the current access token. The token refreshing can be automated in code, but in your approach it will need to be done manually.

Comment: Sure, that would be trivial to solve by just not providing an option for token expiration and have it whatever it would be in the natural flow. The whole reason I am trying to take this approach is because the clients would not want to go through writing code (or are not capable of) just for OAuth. Additionally my API's would be on HTTPS so getting hold of access token would not be trivial. Not sure I understand your point of someone getting access to the client id and access token, since if that happens I'd be screwed irrespective of what approach I take.

Comment: HTTPS is good as long as you have code taking care of Oauth. But once you make this manual, you can't rely on the developer to make sure he only uses it in the right places. It might be exchanged over email, chat, post it notes and what not. Added with the no-expire on generated access tokens, this just increases the probability of some screw up happening with time.